# Grab current first and last day in week in php

Tags: php

How do I grab and show dates for the first and last day in the current week we're in.

So in this current week it would output:

```
2012-05-14  -  2012-05-20
```

(It's 2012-05-17 today)

How can this be done simply?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

```
$first = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("last monday"));
$last = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("next sunday"));
```

other examples

```
strtotime('monday this week');
strtotime('sunday this week');
```