# Finding first and last day of the week (or month, quarter, or year)

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grab current first and last day in week in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634739/grab-current-first-and-last-day-in-week-in-php)

I am trying to get the first and last day of the week, month, quarter, and year for a given day.

For instance, for day  2013-01-16, the first and last days would be:

- Week - It would be 2013-01-13 and 2013-01-19 (assuming Sunday to Saturday)
- Month - It would be 2013-01-01 and 2013-01-31
- Quarter - It would be 2013-01-01 and 2013-03-31
- Year - It would be 2013-01-01 and 2013-12-31

My purpose is to include them in a `WHERE myDate BETWEEN 2013-01-13 AND 2013-01-19`.

Both a standard MYSQL function solution (but not stored procedure, etc) or PHP solution is acceptable.  Thank you

---

Solution for first and last day of given quarter.

```
$q=ceil($date->format("n")/3);
$months_start=array('January','April','July','October');
$months_end=array('March','June','September','December');
$m_start=$months_start[$q-1];
$m_end=$months_end[$q-1];
$modifier='first day of '.$m_start.' '.$date->format('Y');
$date->modify($modifier);
echo $modifier.': '.$date->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
$modifier='last day of '.$m_end.' '.$date->format('Y');
$date->modify($modifier);
echo $modifier.': '.$date->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=first+and+last+day+of+the+week+php and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=first+and+last+day+of+the+month+php

Comment: Yes, these do look like good examples using PHP.  I was previously looking for a MySQL solution and spent more time searching those.  I will definitely check out these solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$date = strtotime('2013-01-16');

// First/last day of week 
$first = strtotime('last Sunday');
$last = strtotime('next Saturday');
```

Or PHP's native [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) functionality:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-16');

// First/last day of month
$first = $date->modify('first day of this month');
$last = $date->modify('last day of this month');
```

---

Getting the first/last day of a year might be a little bit more tricky:

```
// Get date
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-16');

// Format to get date
$year = $date->format('Y');

// Get first day of Jan and last day of Dec
$first = $date->modify("first day of January $year");
$last = $date->modify("last day of December $year");
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  I will give it a try.  "first day of this month" however, seems to loosy goosy and scares me!

Comment: When it says "first day of this month", it's relative to the date you specified (i.e. 2013-01-16). It makes sense: for **this** month, give me the **first** day.

Comment: Struggling with "first day of this year".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  Just coming back to post my answer back to you :) I ended up using this.  first day of January '.$date->format('Y').  Would have been nice if "this" worked, but all is well that ends well.

Comment: Very last one!  How about quarter?  MySQL supports quarter, but I don't believe PHP does.

Comment: Don't think they do, no. Probably best to stick to using months for quarters. Check http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  I came up with a solution and added it to my original post.  If you have any recommendations, please comment.  Thanks